# AWS problem accessing Spring cloud eureka server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am migrating my spring cloud eureka application to AWS ECS and currently having some trouble doing so.

I have an ECS cluster on AWS in which an EC2 service of eureka-server
is running on it. in this service, there is a task running

**My problem is that:**

For my Eureka-server task, it suppose to run on External Link 18.136.147.71:8761 , but it isn't.This 18.136.147.71 is an auto assigned IP by AWS. the only setting i made was allocating an Elastic IP via EC2 Panel.

Although from CloudWatch log i can see that the service is running normal, i am unable to access the link as it always gives this error

```
This site can’t be reached. 18.136.147.71:8761 took too long to respond.
```

**what are some possible errors that might have lead to this problem?
there is no problem with the docker image because i am able to run it locally on my computer.**

below are my CloudWatch Log. This log is exactly the same as my local terminal output when i run the docker image locally:

```
2018-11-21 04:10:13.567 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1376c05c: startup date [Wed Nov 21 04:10:13 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-21 04:10:15.178 INFO 1 --- [ main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-11-21 04:10:15.366 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e4594e4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
. ____ _ __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )
' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot :: (v1.5.2.RELEASE)
2018-11-21 04:10:18.870 INFO 1 --- [ main] eureka.server.ServerApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-21 04:10:18.972 INFO 1 --- [ main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@735b5592: startup date [Wed Nov 21 04:10:18 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1376c05c
2018-11-21 04:10:24.655 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope : BeanFactory id=1ce1cdc0-5c4b-3c0c-ae18-58ba57b52bb6
2018-11-21 04:10:24.681 INFO 1 --- [ main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-11-21 04:10:25.164 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94583828] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-11-21 04:10:25.179 INFO 1 --- [ main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e4594e4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-11-21 04:10:26.276 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2018-11-21 04:10:26.370 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting service Tomcat
2018-11-21 04:10:26.371 INFO 1 --- [ main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2018-11-21 04:10:26.775 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-11-21 04:10:26.775 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7803 ms
2018-11-21 04:10:29.661 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.662 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.662 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.662 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.662 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.664 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'webRequestTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.664 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.664 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-21 04:10:29.665 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-11-21 04:10:30.190 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2018-11-21 04:10:30.676 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-11-21 04:10:30.677 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-11-21 04:10:31.261 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-11-21 04:10:31.262 INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-11-21 04:10:34.871 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@735b5592: startup date [Wed Nov 21 04:10:18 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1376c05c
2018-11-21 04:10:35.375 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-11-21 04:10:35.376 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-11-21 04:10:35.380 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/lastn],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.lastn(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2018-11-21 04:10:35.380 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.status(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2018-11-21 04:10:35.482 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-11-21 04:10:35.482 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-11-21 04:10:35.758 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-11-21 04:10:38.472 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.473 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.474 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.475 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/restart || /restart.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.475 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/archaius || /archaius.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.476 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.479 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.556 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.556 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.557 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.557 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/resume || /resume.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.558 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.559 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.559 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.560 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.560 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.565 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
2018-11-21 04:10:38.565 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.568 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.568 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.568 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/features || /features.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.569 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.569 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.570 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.570 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/pause || /pause.json],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.570 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/service-registry/instance-status],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint.getStatus()
2018-11-21 04:10:38.570 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/service-registry/instance-status],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint.setStatus(java.lang.String)
2018-11-21 04:10:38.989 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader : SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@735b5592: startup date [Wed Nov 21 04:10:18 GMT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1376c05c] and template loader path [classpath:/templates/]
2018-11-21 04:10:38.990 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer : ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
2018-11-21 04:10:39.462 WARN 1 --- [ main] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2018-11-21 04:10:39.470 WARN 1 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-11-21 04:10:39.471 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-11-21 04:10:39.486 WARN 1 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-11-21 04:10:39.555 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-11-21 04:10:39.760 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-11-21 04:10:39.979 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-11-21 04:10:39.980 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2018-11-21 04:10:40.073 INFO 1 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1542773440073 with initial instances count: 0
2018-11-21 04:10:40.557 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext : Initializing ...
2018-11-21 04:10:40.562 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2018-11-21 04:10:41.886 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-11-21 04:10:41.887 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-11-21 04:10:41.887 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-11-21 04:10:41.887 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-11-21 04:10:42.568 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes : Replica node URL: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2018-11-21 04:10:42.577 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2018-11-21 04:10:42.577 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext : Initialized
2018-11-21 04:10:42.859 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-11-21 04:10:42.868 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-11-21 04:10:42.869 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-11-21 04:10:42.870 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-11-21 04:10:42.870 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-11-21 04:10:42.871 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'serviceRegistryEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-11-21 04:10:42.872 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-11-21 04:10:42.874 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2018-11-21 04:10:42.964 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
2018-11-21 04:10:42.974 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'serviceRegistryEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint:name=serviceRegistryEndpoint,type=ServiceRegistryEndpoint]
2018-11-21 04:10:42.980 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2018-11-21 04:10:43.068 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=735b5592,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2018-11-21 04:10:43.072 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter : Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.endpoint:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
2018-11-21 04:10:43.773 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-11-21 04:10:43.774 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry : Registering application unknown with eureka with status UP
2018-11-21 04:10:43.973 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap : Setting the eureka configuration..
2018-11-21 04:10:43.974 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap : Eureka data center value eureka.datacenter is not set, defaulting to default
2018-11-21 04:10:43.974 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap : Eureka environment value eureka.environment is not set, defaulting to test
2018-11-21 04:10:44.071 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap : isAws returned false
2018-11-21 04:10:44.071 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap : Initialized server context
2018-11-21 04:10:44.072 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2018-11-21 04:10:44.072 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl : Renew threshold is: 1
2018-11-21 04:10:44.072 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl : Changing status to UP
2018-11-21 04:10:44.165 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-11] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2018-11-21 04:10:44.367 INFO 1 --- [ main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http)
2018-11-21 04:10:44.369 INFO 1 --- [ main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2018-11-21 04:10:44.372 INFO 1 --- [ main] eureka.server.ServerApplication : Started ServerApplication in 33.505 seconds (JVM running for 36.231)
2018-11-21 04:11:44.159 INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2018-11-21 04:12:44.159 INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question. The reason was because the inbound rule for my Security group was not set.

Steps to set

EC2->Security Groups-> Choose your security group --> Inbound tab --> Edit --> set the port